# Teams App - Integrations within the Files tab

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft365, microsoft-teams-js

Is it possible to modify any of the context menus from the Files tab in Teams?  I would like to add some functionality to download these files to my application.

[Files tab in Microsoft Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVNz8.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way to extend Sharepoint doclib/list, including FileHandler([Add custom actions to files - OneDrive - OneDrive dev center | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/file-handlers/define-actions?view=odsp-graph-online)), SPFX extensions ([Build your first ListView Command Set extension | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api)) or Custom Formatter ([Command bar customization syntax reference | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-commandbar-formatting)).

It is not specific to Channel Files tab. It is generic extension for SharePoint doclib/list, once user apply the extension on the associated SharePoint document library.

Iframe based CFT will ensure once the extension show up in SharePoint web app, it will also show up in Teams Channel Files tab.